# minutes between a date and a string time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a starting hour given in string.

```
let opens = '08:00';
```

I want to measure the difference in minutes for various dates.

```
let date1 = moment('1945.10.20 17:30');
let date2 = moment('1970.01.08 12:00');
// should result 570 (9.5h) and 240 (4h)
```

I was naive enough to try

```
moment(opens, 'HH:mm').diff(date1, 'm');
```

but I realized that it would make a date for the current day's hour.

Comment: You would need to construct a datetime using the same date (day, month and year) as the one you wish to diff against, then do your diff check.

Comment: Why do you add a date to the mix? If you just need to see the diff  between current time and some opening time, I'd try without momentjs

Comment: What date do you want to start/compare with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a moment object on the same day, but with the hours you want. From there do the comparison. If you know the format of opens will always be `HH:mm` then you can do this:

```
let opens = '08:00';
let opensTime = moment(opens, 'HH:mm');
let date1 = moment('1945.10.20 17:30', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH:mm');
let openDate1 = date1.clone().set({
    hour: opensTime.hour(),
    minute: opensTime.minute()
});
```

Then compare:

```
date1.diff(openDate1, 'm') === 570;
```

Alternatively, you could just do a split on `opens`—`opens.split(":")`—to get the hour and minute.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly, you want to compare the hours on your date object to 8AM.

Javascript has getHours() and getMinutes() from date object.

```
Hence you can do date.getHours() - 8, and date1.getMinutes()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the `opens` variable?

```js
let date1 = moment(new Date('1945.10.20 17:30'));
let date2 = moment(new Date('1970.01.08 12:00'));

function timeDifference(end, opensHour, opensMinute) {
  var start = end.clone().set({
    "hour": opensHour,
    "minute": opensMinute
  });

  return {
    "start": start,
    "end": end,
    "difference": end.diff(start, "minutes")
  };
}

console.log(timeDifference(date1, 8, 0));
console.log(timeDifference(date2, 8, 0));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Essentially what you need to do is, once you have the end dates, create a new moment with the same date but your `opens` start time. Then do the difference.

Or, you could also subtract:

```js
let opens = "08:00";
let date1 = moment(new Date('1945.10.20 17:30'));
let date2 = moment(new Date('1970.01.08 12:00'));

function timeDifference(opens, end) {
  // get the start
  var start = moment(opens, "HH:mm");
  
  // find how many minutes from midnight the start is
  var startFromMidnight = start.diff(start.clone().startOf("day"), "minutes");
  
  // find how many minutes from midnight the end is
  var endFromMidnight = end.diff(end.clone().startOf("day"), "minutes");
  
  // subtract the two to find the difference
  return endFromMidnight - startFromMidnight;
}

console.log(timeDifference("08:00", date1));
console.log(timeDifference("08:00", date2));
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```